# Windows visual c++ why is 'Start Debugging' disabled?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I've set build configuration to be 'Debug'. It builds without error. The output debug exe file is there and in the Debug directory. But the Debug->'Start Debugging' option is greyed out so I can't select it. However 'Start without Debugging' is there and is selectable.

Comment: needed to add the project to 'set as startup project'

Comment: For me nothin worked other than a repair on vs2017

Answer (score 2):

needed to add the project to 'set as startup project'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @XaverKapeller actually, it does answer the question (although without much explanation). Also, the person who posted the question is the same person who answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem.
Seems that this occurs when there is more than one project in the solution. Then one of the projects has to be set as start up project to fix it. Select the right project, and click Project -> Set as start up project.